# Android Gradle - How to include local .jar files as dependencies from outside the project directory

Tags: android, gradle, path, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm working on a project that's suppossed to be running offline and I'm trying to include local `.jar` files as dependencies inside the `build.gradle (app)`

The structure of the repo can be seen here:
[image]

The main project is inside the `dev` folder.

In the `submodules` folder I have all the `app` and `build` dependencies along with the `android-sdk, gradle plugin` and `jdk`.

Trying to include all my jar files inside the `build.gradle(app)` like this:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '../../submodules/app_dependencies')
```

Doesn't work because I'm referencing a path outside of the project's directory and when I try to build the app I get The following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:androidDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:developDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.61.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.61 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.61 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.61 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.61 available for offline mode.
```

Debugging this I see the message `No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.61' in repository 'maven'` when it's looking in the following path:

```
file:/C:/Users/my-user-name/Desktop/android_repo/client-android/dev/submodules/dependencies/build_dependencies/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime/1.3.61/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.3.61.jar
```

for some reason, even if I added `../../` in the `filetree(dir)`, gradle is still searching inside the `dev` directory and my dependencies are above in the `submodules`.

Is there a way to specify a dynamic path inside `build.gradle` that's outside of the project's directory?

Answer (score 0):

It works with files (in kotlin notation):

```
dependencies {
    implementation(files("../../submodules/app_dependencies/your-library.jar"))
}
```

If you need to include all files from some folder, you can just build a list of all jars in some directory and use it as `files()` argument.